Constructing a density function from a condtion
Consider a density function  that has its support in the interval [0,]. Additionally, we know that for a fixed ℎ>1 and a fixed ∈(0,1), the following condition holds:
ℎ(ℎ)+(1−)()=1/.
I am considering to construct a density function  from the above condition.
If ℎ=1, we can clearly set ()=1/ in the interval [0,], which corresponds to a uniform distribution. However, with ℎ>1, the problem becomes somewhat complicated. Assuming ()=1/(ℎ+(1−)), this function works fine as long as  is below 2/ℎ (assuming  has strictly positive support up to some 2). However, for sufficiently large values of , () would be strictly positive, but (ℎ) would be zero, implying that the equality cannot be satisfied.
Therefore, I am wondering if there is a simpler way of constructing the density function.

Write your functional equation as
$$ f(x) = \frac{1/\nu - \theta h f(xh)}{1-\theta}$$
You have $f(x) = 0$ for $x > \nu$.  Thus
for $\nu \ge x > \nu/h$ you must have
$f(x) = 1/(\nu (1-\theta))$.
And then for $\nu/h \ge x > \nu/h^2$,
$f(x) = (1-(1+h)\theta)/(\nu (1-\theta)^2)$.  By induction you can show that
$$ f(x) = \frac{1 - (-h \theta/(1-\theta))^n}{\nu(1 + (h-1)\theta)}\ 
\text{for} \frac{\nu}{h^{n-1}} \ge x > \frac{\nu}{h^n}$$
Of course, if $h > 1/\theta - 1$ this will not give you a proper density, as $f$ will take negative values when $n$ is even.
But for $h \le 1/\theta - 1$ it will work.
